# Install Adobe Air 2.6 on Ubuntu

Tags: flash, ubuntu, air, adobe, installation

6 month ago, I installed Adobe Air on my Ubuntu (12.04) and it worked fine since then.
A week ago, all my air applications display changed. They appear with a lof of green and only half size of the window, and the mouse dind't have much effect on them.

So I tried to re-install Adobe Air like I didn't a couple of months ago. But still the same result. I re-installed my Ubuntu 12.04. Still the same. I was working on 64 bit. So I tried the 32 bit version on Ubuntu, but it didn't solve my problem.

I tried installing each version of Adobe Air, and I realized than only the version 1.5 still displays fine. But it's too old for my applications.

Here the way Adobe Air looks when I try to install it, and all the Air applications look the same :

[image: Hey a screen shot]

It's been 4 days that i am trying to solve that problem. Did anybody experienced the same problem ?

Comment: Finally, after 4 days struggling. This morning I authorised updates on unbuntu and installed them. And Adobe Air and works again fine...

Comment: Today In rebooted again the server, and the problem showed up again...

Answer (score 0):

I finally find what the problem was. It has nothing to do with either the server, neither Flash Player or Adobe Air. The problem came from mstc window (remote desktop software). By default it was set to display 16bit colors. I might have changed it sometime to 15bit.

By setting it to 16bit, it solved the problem.

[image]